# Decode base64 string and write to file

Tags: ruby, base64

I'm trying to read file which contains encoded base64 string and write decoded output into another file. My `Input.txt` contains a base64 string, something like:

```
PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz48cmV2aWV3LWNhc2UgY3JlYXRl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\r\nIG5hbWU9IlBob25lTnVtYmVyIiB2YWx1
```

This string is created on server side with Java apache codec.binary.Base64 library. This string is captured with Fiddler when two different web services communicates with each other. Sometimes I have no access to the another web-service, that is why I sniff messages between services. In addition I use Ruby to automate some routine tasks and decided this time to use Ruby again. For encoding captured base64 string I use next snippet of code:

```
require "base64"

content = File.read('Input.txt')
decode_base64_content = Base64.decode64(content) 
File.open("Output.txt", "wb") do |f|
  f.write(decode_base64_content)
end
```

But output looks malformed, like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><review-case create®vFFSТ#2фЦ"у#B“ЈCЈS"7—7FVУТ%G&f–wW&хFVЧЖFUфЦзnagement_v5.1" ba` and so on. Can you please advise on what I'm doing wrong? I use Ruby 1.9.3 on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Can you share the original base64 encoded string fully?

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is 'no'. Firstly, it contains data about company I work for, secondly, input file contains about 81.000 characters.

Comment: Your code looks OK. Try doing the strict decode64 and see what error it throws.

Comment: Did you encode the original context with the reverse method? If not you would have to make sure that the same `Base64` definition is used. There are at least three in use in `module Base64` alone (RFC 2045, RFC 4648 (`strict_...` and the `url safe_...` variant).

Comment: Yes, can you provide an encoded string for us (not the sensitive one, but find what method was used to create that and post it here, along with an encoded example or something.)

Comment: Hmmh, the [documentation of the apache Base64 library for Java](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) refers to RFC 2045, so the regular `decode` should be your best bet. However it takes care to tell you that the line separator (default) is `CRLF ("\r\n")` which is reflected in your example. Do you get the same result on Windows and Ubuntu? I do not know if different line endings would confuse Base64, but it is at least a possibility. Try to encode a known plaintext with Ruby and compare the resulting byte sequence.

Comment: Results are the same for Windows and Ubuntu. I get `invalid base64 (ArgumentError)` when trying to use strict_decode64 because of next from documentation "ArgumentError is raised if str is incorrectly padded or contains non-alphabet characters".

Comment: @MikeH-R The [documentation for `module Base64`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html) tells you: "Returns the Base64-encoded version of bin. This method complies with RFC 2045. Line feeds are added to every 60 encoded characters." So it will probably not expect the additional `CR`, try getting rid of it with `gsub("\r", '')`. `decode64` should (probably) be able to deal with a line length of 76.

Comment: @Patru Thanks, but still have no success. I have to try to encode my string with the same library as it is created. But I believe there should be solution in Ruby.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I do not know how you manage to do this, but the line endings `\r\n` in your string seem to be there as 4-byte character sequences, not as 2-byte escaped `CRLF`. If I copy your file into a ruby string with single ticks:

```
unescaped='PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz48cmV2aWV3LWNhc2UgY3JlYXRl\r\nZGF0ZT0iMTMvTWFyLzIwMTQgMDk6MDQ6NTEiIHN5c3RlbT0iVHJhZmlndXJhX1RlbXBsYXRlX01h\r\nbmFnZW1lbnRfdjUuMSIgYmF0Y2hpZD0iMCIgdHJhbnNhY3Rpb25ubz0iMSIgYmF0Y2huYW1lPSJH'
Base64.decode64(unescaped)
#=> garbled text for every second line
```

if I do the same with double quotes (which respect the escape sequences):

```
escaped="PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz48cmV2aWV3LWNhc2UgY3JlYXRl\r\nZGF0ZT0iMTMvTWFyLzIwMTQgMDk6MDQ6NTEiIHN5c3RlbT0iVHJhZmlndXJhX1RlbXBsYXRlX01h\r\nbmFnZW1lbnRfdjUuMSIgYmF0Y2hpZD0iMCIgdHJhbnNhY3Rpb25ubz0iMSIgYmF0Y2huYW1lPSJH"
Base64.decode64(escaped)
#=> all is well that ends well
```

Therefore the problem seems to occur when you write the file. It can be amended in Ruby though:

```
unescaped='PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz48cmV2aWV3LWNhc2UgY3JlYXRl\r\nZGF0ZT0iMTMvTWFyLzIwMTQgMDk6MDQ6NTEiIHN5c3RlbT0iVHJhZmlndXJhX1RlbXBsYXRlX01h\r\nbmFnZW1lbnRfdjUuMSIgYmF0Y2hpZD0iMCIgdHJhbnNhY3Rpb25ubz0iMSIgYmF0Y2huYW1lPSJH'
Base64.decode64(unescaped)
escaped=unescaped.gsub('\\r', "\r").gsub('\\n', "\n")
Base64.decode64(escaped)
#=> now you should be fine again
```

but of course the correct solution would be to store the file correctly.

Given your current file the following should work:

```
require "base64"

content = File.read('Input.txt')
content.gsub!('\\r', "\r")
content.gsub!('\\n', "\n")
decode_base64_content = Base64.decode64(content) 
File.open("Output.txt", "wb") do |f|
  f.write(decode_base64_content)
end
```

Please do post some output if it does not.

Comment: It works if I use double quotes and specify encoded string in ruby file. But still have no success if I try to get encoded string from file. Thanks for your help. At least it works and if no other variants will be suggested I ought to accept your answer.

Comment: @olyv: How comes your file is written this way? You should write it with proper newlines (in any convention) and not with escape characters. If you read the whole file as in your sample code it should work by adding `content.gsub!('\\r', "\r")` and `content.gsub!('\\n', "\n")` before decoding (note the exclamation mark, `gsub!` will modify the string in place instead of creating a copy).